# Taking weighted average over overlapping polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, overlapping-features, average, weighted

I am trying to find source emissions values for a roads lines layer based on emissions rates tied to polygons.

Here is an illustrative depiction of the two layers I am working with:

[image]

Each polygon has tied to it an emissions rate and a vehicle population count. On top of that, I have a roads lines layer that has traffic counts for each road segment (blue to green to yellow to red, going from lowest traffic counts to highest traffic counts).

For all overlapped sections of the polygons layer, I want to find the average emissions rate of all polygons that make up that overlapped zone, but weighted by the vehicle populations of those polygons. The reason for the weighting is that polygons would not have equal influence in an averaged emissions rate, since the polygons in this layer will all have different vehicle population counts, and thus have varying degrees of influence.

The goal is to have each overlapped region assigned its own unique averaged emissions rate to be multiplied by the road segments within the polygons, to then calculate a source emissions value for each road segment.

Can this weighted average task for the overlapped polygons be done in QGIS?

Comment: These lines: are they already split into red/yellow/green/blue linestrings?

Comment: from my understanding they should be aready splitted since they have different attributes.

Comment: Yes it can be done, what have you tried?

Comment: For such questions, it helps a lot to provide the project with your data (even if dummy data, but with the correct structure). This would help a l lot to understand the problem. Otherwise, people willing to help first have to create their own testing data and they might not correspond to the structure (including attributes, geometry, topology) that you have.

Comment: @Taras - The red/yellow/green/blue segments are distinguished in the attribute table, such that each segment has its own color and row in the attribute table. The red/yellow/green/blue aspect was just a graduated color ramp I applied through symbology.

Comment: @eurojam - Yes, each line segment has its own row in the attribute table.

Comment: @BERA - I have tried intersection and union, but the challenge is that I am not sure how to find the average of the overlapped areas that can be weighted by the population counts of each of the associated polygons. I don't know what tool to use for that.

Comment: @Babel-I can provide some links to some spatial data to use. There are just to data layers I would need to share: 1) block groups polygons layer and 2) and lines layer made up of segments containing different values. I would look for appropriate data to share here.

Comment: @LostinSpatialAnalysis, you can add what you have tried to your question post, so it is easier for people to understand where you get stuck